# Google App Engine Python HTML Table

Tags: python, html, html-table

I am trying to create a table within a Google App Engine Application where the background color in a table changes periodically based on input. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?
Here is my code:

```
    self.response.out.write("""
         <img src="/images/resistor.png" width = "150">
         <table border = "1">
         <tr height="150" >
         <td bgcolor="%s" width="35">  </td> <td bgcolor="%s" width="35">  </td> <td bgcolor="%s" width="35">  </td> <td bgcolor="%s" width="35"> </td> %(Red,Blue,Black,Green)
         </tr>
         </table>
          <form action="/sign" method="post">
            <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
          </form> """)
    self.response.out.write('</pre></body></html>')
```

For example the Red,Green... Colors in %( ) will be variables that will change so at one point they all may be Red or Blue and Yellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That type of string-formatting is deprecated](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples). Please use the `.format()` method in new code. Example:

```
self.response.out.write("""
     <img src="/images/resistor.png" width = "150">
     <table border = "1">
       <tr height="150" >
         <td bgcolor="{}" width="35">  </td> 
         <td bgcolor="{}" width="35">  </td> 
         <td bgcolor="{}" width="35">  </td> 
         <td bgcolor="{}" width="35">  </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <form action="/sign" method="post">
       <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
       <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
     </form> """.format( ('Red','Blue','Black','Green') ))
self.response.out.write('</pre></body></html>')
```

And for anything beyond the basic have a look at using templates. Examples of templating systems are Jinja2 and Django Templates.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I am getting the error                    File "/Users/ben/Desktop/theresistorpage/main.py", line 116, in post
    </form> """.format( ('Red','Blue','Black','Green') ))
IndexError: tuple index out of range